# Cannot invoke java.x.swing.ActionMap.remove(Object) because the return value of "javax.swing.AbstractButton.getActionMap() is null

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception

I'm getting an error with my Swing application and I can't for the life of me figure it out.

I have figured the error occurs on the `aToggleButton.setUI((ButtonUI)primaryUI)` line but I can't find a fix. I don't want to just comment it out as it will mess up the look of the application.

Without the error I am expecting the application to load up and the side application bar to be properly decorated with the linked image in the PrimaryNavigationButtonUI class.

Exception Log:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke
    "javax.swing.ActionMap.remove(Object)" because the return value of
    "javax.swing.AbstractButton.getActionMap()" is null     at
    java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonUI.uninstallListeners(BasicButtonUI.java:262)
        at
    java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonUI.uninstallUI(BasicButtonUI.java:229)
        at
    java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.uninstallUIAndProperties(JComponent.java:755)
        at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.setUI(JComponent.java:730)   at
    java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.setUI(AbstractButton.java:1758)
```

AppMenuToggleButtonDecorator:

```
package com.cthsprojects.apphost.ui.decorator;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;

import javax.swing.JToggleButton;
import javax.swing.plaf.ButtonUI;

import com.cthsprojects.common.ui.theme.SPrimaryNavigationToggleButtonUI;
import com.cthsprojects.common.ui.theme.SToggleButtonUI;
import com.cthsprojects.common.ui.util.SwingUtils;
import com.cthsprojects.common.view.adapters.decorators.AdapterDecorator;

public class AppMenuToggleButtonDecorator implements AdapterDecorator<JToggleButton> {
    
    public static final int BUTTON_PRIMARY_NAVIGATION_STANDARD_WIDTH = 116;
    
    public static final int BUTTON_PRIMARY_NAVIGATION_STANDARD_HEIGHT = SwingUtils.scaleY(50);
    
    public static final Dimension BUTTON_PRIMARY_NAVIGATION_STANDARD_SIZE = new Dimension(116, BUTTON_PRIMARY_NAVIGATION_STANDARD_HEIGHT);
    
    private static SPrimaryNavigationToggleButtonUI primaryUI = new SPrimaryNavigationToggleButtonUI();
    
    private static final Font FONT_PRIMARY_NAVIGATION_BUTTON = new Font("Tahoma", 0, 16);
    
    public void decorate(JToggleButton aToggleButton) {
        if (aToggleButton != null && primaryUI != null) {
            System.out.println("aToggleButton equals " + aToggleButton + ". primaryUI equals " + primaryUI);
            aToggleButton.setFont(FONT_PRIMARY_NAVIGATION_BUTTON);
            aToggleButton.setPreferredSize(BUTTON_PRIMARY_NAVIGATION_STANDARD_SIZE);
            aToggleButton.setUI((ButtonUI)getUI());
        }
    }
    
    protected SToggleButtonUI getUI() {
        return (SToggleButtonUI)primaryUI;
    }
}
```

SPrimaryNavigationToggleButtonUI:

```
package com.cthsprojects.common.ui.theme;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import javax.swing.AbstractButton;
import javax.swing.ButtonModel;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.plaf.ComponentUI;

public class SPrimaryNavigationToggleButtonUI extends SToggleButtonUI {
    
    public static ComponentUI createUI(JComponent component) {
        return new SPrimaryNavigationToggleButtonUI();
    }
    
    @Override
    protected Image getButtonImage(AbstractButton abstractButton) {
        Image image = PropertyTheme.toggleButtonPrimaryNavigationBackgroundImage.getImage();
        return image;
    }
    
    @Override
    protected Image getButtonPressedImage(AbstractButton abstractButton) {
        return PropertyTheme.toggleButtonPrimaryNavigationDepressedImage.getImage();
    }
    
    @Override
    protected void paintTickOnSelection(AbstractButton abstractButton, ButtonModel model) {
    }
    
    @Override
    protected void setModelEnabledGraphicsColor(Graphics graphics, ButtonModel model) {
        if ((model.isArmed() && model.isPressed()) || model.isSelected()) {
            graphics.setColor(PropertyTheme.BUTTON_DEFAULT_PRESSED_FOREGROUND_COLOR);
        }
        else {
            graphics.setColor(PropertyTheme.toggleButtonPrimaryNavigationForegroundColor);
        }
    }
    
    @Override
    protected void setColorForDisabledButton(Graphics graphics) {
        graphics.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    }
}
```

Edit - Tried using EDT but still threw same error with this modified code:

```
package com.cthsprojects.apphost.ui.decorator;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;

import javax.swing.JToggleButton;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.plaf.ButtonUI;

import com.cthsprojects.common.ui.theme.SPrimaryNavigationToggleButtonUI;
import com.cthsprojects.common.ui.theme.SToggleButtonUI;
import com.cthsprojects.common.ui.util.SwingUtils;
import com.cthsprojects.common.view.adapters.decorators.AdapterDecorator;

public class AppMenuToggleButtonDecorator implements AdapterDecorator<JToggleButton> {
    
    public static final int BUTTON_PRIMARY_NAVIGATION_STANDARD_WIDTH = 116;
    
    public static final int BUTTON_PRIMARY_NAVIGATION_STANDARD_HEIGHT = SwingUtils.scaleY(50);
    
    public static final Dimension BUTTON_PRIMARY_NAVIGATION_STANDARD_SIZE = new Dimension(116, BUTTON_PRIMARY_NAVIGATION_STANDARD_HEIGHT);
    
    private static SPrimaryNavigationToggleButtonUI primaryUI = new SPrimaryNavigationToggleButtonUI();
    
    private static final Font FONT_PRIMARY_NAVIGATION_BUTTON = new Font("Tahoma", 0, 16);
    
    public void decorate(final JToggleButton aToggleButton) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {    
            public void run() {
                aToggleButton.setFont(FONT_PRIMARY_NAVIGATION_BUTTON);
                aToggleButton.setPreferredSize(BUTTON_PRIMARY_NAVIGATION_STANDARD_SIZE);
                aToggleButton.setUI((ButtonUI)getUI());
            }
        });
    }
    
    protected SToggleButtonUI getUI() {
        return (SToggleButtonUI)primaryUI;
    }
    
}
```

What can I try next?

Comment: Is all of your Swing code being started on the Swing event dispatch thread, or "EDT"?

Comment: I ask because it looks like your code is initiating code deep within the Swing library that is throwing a NPE when trying to dereference a core Swing component, suggesting that it is accessing the component before it has been fully constructed.

Comment: The code is not being ran on the Swing Event Dispatch Thread.

Comment: Well, then that is quite likely your problem. Does the issue go away when it is run on the EDT?

Comment: I tried using the EDT, but the same NullPointer still gets thrown. (See modified class code at the bottom of original post)

Comment: Then you will want to create and post a [mre] with your question. Please review the link which will explain what this is and how it can help you and us.